# How to replace formulas with values in a specific worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that replaces all formulas in specific worksheet named "Import" with the cells resulting values.

I found the following code, but I need this code to only convert the worksheet named "Import". How should I adjust this code to my problem?

```
Sub Value()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast way woud be to get only the cells containing formulas with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` and then loop through the areas to convert them into values.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertFormulasToValues()
    Dim CellsWithFormula As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set CellsWithFormula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not CellsWithFormula Is Nothing Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Dim Area As Range
        For Each Area In CellsWithFormula.Areas
            Area.Value = Area.Value
        Next Area

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub
```

#### Improved version …

… for cells that start with `=`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertFormulasToValues()
    Dim CellsWithFormula As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set CellsWithFormula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not CellsWithFormula Is Nothing Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Dim Area As Range
        For Each Area In CellsWithFormula.Areas
            On Error Resume Next
            Area.Value = Area.Value
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                ConvertArea Area
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next Area

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ConvertArea(ByRef Area As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Area
        On Error Resume Next
            Cell.Value = Cell.Value
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Cell.Value = "'" & Cell.Value
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: @PEH, I tried to run the macro with a larger data set and I received the following error msg: "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error". I think the problem is this line: Area.Value = Area.Value. The macro managed to convert the first area with formulas to values, but the second, third etc. remained unchanged. Do you have any suggestions on this problem?

Comment: What is the result of `Debug.Print Area.Address` in case of error?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about here. Should I add this to the code and then run it again?

Comment: Yes add it right before the line `Area.Value = Area.Value` run it again and then check the immediate window in VB-Editor what was printed there.

Comment: It shows $L$86. The content in this cell is somewhat different: "=403,50 usd/m. I buy those". This is from a conversation. Do you know why this is happening, or a way to come around this problem?

Comment: @PEH Probably something like if sentence starts with "=" then add ' before the equality sign?

Comment: @Jan Actually that's the issue, the content of the cell starts with a `=` sign and excel thinks this should be a formula and trys to convert it into a formula which (of courser) fails. Can you avoid the `=` sign somehow? Cells that are not formulas should not start with a `=` sign.

Comment: This is imported data, so I cannot avoid this. However, this issue is very unlikely to occur.

Comment: @Jan You can avoid the issue if you format the cells as text (`.NumberFormat`) before you do the formula conversion. But this will only work if there is no numbers eg in that column (otherwise you will end up with numbers saved as strings).

Comment: @Jan have a look at my improved version. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @PEH Tanks! I will try this out later:) I should probably include "+" and "-" in the code as well. How should I implement that into the updated code?

Comment: @Jan why `+` and `-`? Excel handles them as plain text if it does not begin with `=` anyway the code just converts the complete cell into text in case of errors. So actually it just adds a `'` as first character which indicates Excel that the content is text and not a formula. Excel ignores the `'` and doesn't show it in the cell.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a worksheet object that you can then loop through. Something simple like this:

```vb
Sub ValueReplace()

    Dim wsImport As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set wsImport = Sheets("Import")

    For Each myCell In wsImport.UsedRange
        If myCell.HasFormula = True Then
            myCell.Value = myCell.Value
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Edit:

The faster method, if you don't want to run a `.HasFormula` check is to simply set the entire `.UsedRange` to value. See below. This should be fast and efficient!

```vb
Sub ValueReplace()

    Dim wsImport As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set wsImport = Sheets("Import")

    wsImport.UsedRange.Value = wsImport.UsedRange.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: @Dean Thanks! I will try to understand your code as well. However, PEH's code worked fine:)

Comment: I like the simplicity of your second approach! Didn't tried it on a large sheet having many formulas though

Answer (score 0):

We can check each cell using a `For Each…Next` loop.

After identifying the cells, we can check whether they contain formulas using the `HasFormula` property. This returns a Boolean value. If the `HasFormula` returns `TRUE`, then our code overwrites the formula by setting the cell value into the Formula property of the cell.

```
Sub Value()

    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Sheets("Import").UsedRange

        If rng.HasFormula Then

            rng.Formula = rng.Value

        End If

    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jan how much formula do you have ? It could explain long processing time

Answer (score 0):

Where 'mySheet' is your active worksheet object:

```
mySheet.UsedRange.Value = mySheet.UsedRange.Value
```

So:

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim xlBook As Object
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

Dim mySheet As Object
Set mySheet = xlBook.Sheets("name of sheet/tab in workbook")

mySheet.UsedRange.Value = mySheet.UsedRange.Value
```